# How to not duplicate fields declaration (Selenium)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation

Website consist of many modal forms, those all modal forms do have same input fields for example : Name and Surname however those modal forms do have elements that are unique to a specific modal form for example:

Modal window 1 consist of: Name,Surname and Age
Modal windows 2    consist of: Name,Surname and Country

How would i abstract the name and surname and at the same time insatiate them when one or another modal loaded. My current approach is that i repeat elements and using page factory to instantiate those once object of the modal is created.

Modal 1

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@placeholder='Name']")
private WebElement userName;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@placeholder='Surname']")
private WebElement userSurname;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@placeholder='Age']")
private WebElement age;
```

Modal 2

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@placeholder='Name']")
private WebElement userName;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@placeholder='Surname']")
private WebElement userSurname;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@placeholder='Country']")
private WebElement country;
```

Both of those modals extend from Base page so that the parent gets called and page factory creates objects for my fields

```
public class BasePage {

    public WebDriver driver;
    protected Wait wait;

    public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
        initializePage(driver);
        this.wait = new Wait(driver);
    }

    final protected void initializePage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 20), this);
    }
}
```

I would like to not duplicate fields and have them abstract somewhere, so kindly experienced one give me a hand thanks.

Comment: Why wouldn't you create a `BaseModal` that would extend `BasePage` and that could be a parent for more specific model parts?

Comment: @AlexeyR thanks for your answer, okey what if i have not just modals but also forms on the web where again that name and surname appears ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to deal with "field duplication" in `PageFactory` harness is to build a class hierarchy. Like:

```java
class BaseModal extends BasePage{
    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@placeholder='Name']")
    protected WebElement userName;
    
    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@placeholder='Surname']")
    protected WebElement userSurname;
}
```

If you concern about too complicated tree, you can consider having separate mechanism of page initialization so that you would not bind to a root page class. Like:

```java
class BaseModal {
    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@placeholder='Name']")
    protected WebElement userName;
    
    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@placeholder='Surname']")
    protected WebElement userSurname;
}

class SpecificModal extends BaseModal {
    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@placeholder='Country']")
    protected WebElement country;
}

class PageInitializer {
    WedDriver driver;
    public PageInitializer(WebDriver driver){
       this.driver = driver;
    }
    public void initializePage(Object page){
        PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 20), page);
    }
}
```

So that your code would be:

```java
PageInitializer initializer = new PageInitializer(driver);
SpecificPage  page = new SpecificPage();
initializer.initializePage(page);
```